# Lost connected app org

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps

I created a connected app in some dev org a while back and can't seem to find it.

I want to make a few changes and SFDC isn't being very helpful in finding it.

Is there a way to identify it through the oauth flow or something similar?

I've got the consumer key and consumer secret but am not able to figure out which environment it was created under

Comment: As far as I know, no. But I'll ask around.

Comment: @sfdcfox - much appreciated